# How to post the Images on facebook via code in windows phone?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, sharing

I want to create a windows Phone app using two social services one is Gmail and another one is Facebook.

I use EmailComposeTask for Gmail service and i create the facebook developer account for facebook sharing.

If any FacebookTask is there in windows phone 8 like smsTask, phonetask, and phototask.

Please Help Me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no any Just like this as Emailtask. But you can use Facebook.dll and then after easily use FacebookClient class for implementation of facebook. If you face any problem implementing it let me know I will help you.